# Sort Product Page by Drop Down List (Squarespace)

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Disclaimer: I'm new to coding!

I'm trying to sort products in Squarespace site by Category, which in this case is by State. You can see the site page here: https://www.compasslandusa.com/listings

Right now the Category is shown on the LHS. I want to remove that (can be done easily in site styles) and add a Sort by State Drop Down feature.

I'm currently struggling with the code shown below. My issue is that I don't know how to have the Drop Down connect to the product's Category.

I can easily get the Drop Down to appear on the site, but when I go to select a Category, nothing on the page changes.

You can see the code I'm playing with on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lyzf2cen/).

```js
function sortDropdownList(ddl){

    var options = [].slice.apply(ddl.options, [0]);
    ddl.innerHTML = "";
    var sorted = options.sort(function(a,b){     
       return +(a.innerText) - +(b.innerText);
    });

    for(var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++){
      ddl.options.add(sorted[i]);
    }  

}
    
var parentSelect = document.getElementById("product");
var childSelect = document.getElementById("power");
var options = [].slice.apply(childSelect, [0]);
var emptyOption = options[0];
childSelect.innerHTML = "";

parentSelect.addEventListener("change", function(e){

    var selectedId = parentSelect.options[parentSelect.selectedIndex].id;
    childSelect.innerHTML = "";
    childSelect.options.add(emptyOption);
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){

        if( options[i].getAttribute("data-name") == selectedId ){

           childSelect.options.add(options[i]);

        }
    }

    sortDropdownList(childSelect);

});
```

```html
<table width=100% border="0">
  <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Sort By State:</td>
    <td><select name="product" id="productlist" width="200" style="width: 200px">
      <option></option>
      <option id="Arizona">Arizona</option>
      <option id="Colorado">Colorado</option>
      <option id="Florida">Florida</option>
      <option id="Nevada">Nevada</option>
    </select></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Desired outcome: Working Drop Down that allows visitors to Sort by State, which is the Category per the Squarespace products page.

I really appreciate any help you're willing to provide! Thank you!